# OAuth Token/Secret Change?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I created a very simple application to pull and display videos on a client site from an album. Everything was set up and humming along fine when it suddenly stopped working. After tracking down the problem, it turned out that the OAuth Token and Secret changed without warning last week.

Is this something that will happen periodically? Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo's OAuth tokens will only change if granted via XAuth (username and password auth). If this is how you generated the token, it means the authenticated user changed their password.

If this is not the case, user tokens are additionally revoked any time Vimeo forces a password reset. If you want to find out the exact cause you can contact vimeo directly at https://vimeo.com/help/contact